# No access to .x.x IP range on network

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I have following setup: Cellular network connection for Internet access 2 x Ethetnet LANs with no access

The LANs are 10.5x.x.x networks. My device is on 10.51.85.x subrange. I can ping / reach devices on 10.51.85.x subrange. From the device I need to access another device which is on 10.51.23.x IP range. But I can't see anything in that range. There is another device on the same subrange (10.51.85.191) which sees all devices in 10.51.x.x.

The device is using Ubuntu and Network Manager. This is configuration for interfaces:

```
$ ip route
default via 10.72.0.12 dev wwp0s20u4u1i12 proto static metric 700 
10.51.85.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.51.85.188 metric 100 
10.51.85.1 dev enp1s0 proto static scope link metric 100 
10.72.0.8/29 dev wwp0s20u4u1i12 proto kernel scope link src 10.72.0.11 metric 700 

$ ip a
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:85:84:a5:56:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.51.85.188/24 brd 10.51.85.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fa5d:6bc4:6f6f:ecba/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wwp0s20u4u1i12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:16:f3:0c:fc:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.72.0.11/29 brd 10.72.0.15 scope global noprefixroute wwp0s20u4u1i12
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3271:1c90:a688:a9b0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ping -I enp1s0 10.51.85.191
PING 10.51.85.191 (10.51.85.191) from 10.51.85.188 enp1s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.51.85.191: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.423 ms
64 bytes from 10.51.85.191: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.488 ms
^C
--- 10.51.85.191 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1014ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.423/0.455/0.488/0.038 ms

$ ping -I enp1s0 10.51.23.59
PING 10.51.23.59 (10.51.23.59) from 10.51.85.188 enp1s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.51.23.59 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2055ms
```

Any ideas? Do I have my routing or gateway misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a route to reach the 10.51.23.whatever network, so such traffic is passed to the default gateway. You need to specify a route which tells the machine how to route that traffic.

For example:

```
# ip r add 10.51.23.0/24 via 10.51.85.191
```

Note that this only gets you one way traffic. The other end must also know how to send traffic back to your network, so you will also need to add another route to the appropriate machine(s) there. I can't give you an exact command because the necessary details of that network were not provided. But it will work the same way as any other route.

Comment: Of course, please forgive me the lack of details.
.191 is another device on this network which can access all of the sub ranges (it is windows server machine).
As far as I know the gateway is 10.51.85.1, so I suppose the command should be:
    $ ip r add 10.51.23.0/24 via 10.51.85.1

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. I can now send data to the .23.x subrange.
Do I need to add separate entry for each subrange now? I need to access .19.x and .100.x ranges.
If I do 

    $ ip r add 10.51.0.0/16 via 10.51.85.1

Would this work for all devices?

Comment: @lukMak You will need route entries for every subnet you wish to reach that does not go through the default gateway.